# AlarmManager doesn't start after boot is complete

Tags: android, android-intent, alarmmanager

I need to set the AlaramManager if user chose something from preferences. but I get Unfortunately, stopped Error , where do you think my problem is? thanks

Receiver :

```
public class StartMyServiceAtBootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if ("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED".equals(intent.getAction())) {
            SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager
                    .getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
            if (prefs.getString("autoSend", null) != null) {
                if (prefs.getString("autoSend", "").equals("true")) {
                    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context
                            .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                    Intent i = new Intent(context, AutoSender.class);
                    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i, 0);
                    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                            System.currentTimeMillis(), 1000 * 10, pi);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the Intent:

```
@SuppressLint("Wakelock")
public class AutoSender extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent arg1) {

        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(
                PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "");
        wl.acquire();

        Toast.makeText(context, "Test" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show(); 

        wl.release();
    }

}
```

manifest:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
------------------
 <receiver android:name="AutoSender" >
        </receiver>
        <receiver
            android:name=".StartMyServiceAtBootReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Edit:

and Here is the Exception :

```
08-07 11:21:46.825: E/AndroidRuntime(668): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-07 11:21:46.825: E/AndroidRuntime(668): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.aps.safirsms.StartMyServiceAtBootReceiver: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Boolean cannot be cast to java.lang.String
08-07 11:21:46.825: E/AndroidRuntime(668):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2383)
08-07 11:21:46.825: E/AndroidRuntime(668):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:141)
08-07 11:21:46.825: E/AndroidRuntime(668):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1310)
08-07 11:21:46.825: E/AndroidRuntime(668):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-07 11:21:46.825: E/AndroidRuntime(668):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-07 11:21:46.825: E/AndroidRuntime(668):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
08-07 11:21:46.825: E/AndroidRuntime(668):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-07 11:21:46.825: E/AndroidRuntime(668):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-07 11:21:46.825: E/AndroidRuntime(668):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
08-07 11:21:46.825: E/AndroidRuntime(668):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
08-07 11:21:46.825: E/AndroidRuntime(668):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-07 11:21:46.825: E/AndroidRuntime(668): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Boolean cannot be cast to java.lang.String
08-07 11:21:46.825: E/AndroidRuntime(668):  at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.getString(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:224)
08-07 11:21:46.825: E/AndroidRuntime(668):  at com.aps.safirsms.StartMyServiceAtBootReceiver.onReceive(StartMyServiceAtBootReceiver.java:18)
08-07 11:21:46.825: E/AndroidRuntime(668):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2376)
08-07 11:21:46.825: E/AndroidRuntime(668):  ... 10 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use LogCat to examine the Java stack trace associated with your "stopped Error".

In this case, the problem is probably that you have  `android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"`, which is incorrect. It requires that whoever *sends* that broadcast have that permission, which is not necessarily true.

Comment: I didn't have this at first, but got the error and saw it in some tutorial, so I put it there

Comment: and the thing is the emulator never shuts down, when I try to power it off, the loading dialog goes on for ever and nothing happens.

Comment: @ePezhman: You terminate the emulator by closing it's window, using the facilities your development OS supplies for this (e.g., clicking an X button in the upper right or upper left corner). Then, you can start up a fresh emulator. Install your app on the emulator first, before terminating it, of course, to see if it works properly on the next startup.

Comment: @ePezhman: You have saved a `SharedPreferences` value as a boolean, and you are trying to read it back as a string. Do not do this. Use `getBoolean()` instead of `getString()`. And, to be completely blunt, if you are having difficulty reading that simple Java stack trace, you will have a very difficult time in Android development.

Comment: Thanks :), I didn't know it couldn't show the bool as true or false string

Answer (score 0):

one thing i notice is that you forget the dot in `android:name="AutoSender"` so it should be `android:name=".AutoSender"`.

Also when your BroadcastReceiver isn't in the main package (don't know if it is in your case) you should put the package name in front of it like this `android:name="my.package.name.AutoSender"`

Comment: The dot is not required.